# Where can I ask about web app recommendations?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question on Super User about ["a website to compare software/hardware/electronics"](https://superuser.com/questions/128030/a-website-to-compare-software-hardware-electronics); I was told that questions about web apps are not appropriate for SU. I understand how questions on Facebook can be banned, but I feel that this question is somewhat in a gray zone: I am only looking for a recommendation for software for a specific task. If the question was about desktop software, I guess it would be perfectly valid one.

I see that none of the websites mentioned in [the StackExchange sites list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites) cover this (small) piece of "no man's land". Could you suggest a place to ask this question? Could you also point me to an explanation why all web apps are treated so distinctively?

Comment: See - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42373/what-sites-are-currently-missing-from-the-trilogy - for more information

Comment: Web apps on SU has been treated extensively in this question.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39615/superuser-website-applications-policy

Comment: @Jeff!!! Any update on the progress of a web-app SE-site? My patience with all these questions is overflowing...

Comment: mentioned this on the SU question, but here this might be enough to close-as-duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41570/where-can-i-ask-questions-that-arent-super-user-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ask any questions about web applications on the **[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)** Stack Exchange site.

> **Web Applications - Stack Exchange** is for expert and advanced users of web applications.
>
> If your question generally covers...
>
> - Using Gmail, Facebook, Twitter, Google, or any other website which behaves like an application
> - Bookmarklets
> - Browsers and their features relating to the use of a web application (Greasemonkey scripts for a web application, etc.)

Comment: Good thing we have a site for that now :P  although I think this question was done long before it

Comment: Hehe. Just typing up loose ends ;-)

Comment: Requests for recommendations are explicitly disallowed at Web Apps. [help/on-topic](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): _"Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here: ... Web application recommendation requests"_

Answer (score 4):

Web Apps [no longer accepts requests for Web App recommendations](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2595/354). As [Fish Below the Ice mentions](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/931/where-can-i-ask-about-web-app-recommendations#comment25756_3420), the [Help Center On Topic page](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says:

> Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here:
>
> - Web browsers, including features and browser extensions/add-ons
> - Creating or developing web applications
> - Desktop software
> - Applications for mobile devices such as the Android or iPad
> - Hosted scripts such as Wordpress.org and phpBB
> - Web applications containing adult content
> - **Web application recommendation requests**

*(emphasis mine)*

Depending on what you're looking for, [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) (currently in public beta) might be the right spot, but their requirements for questions is fairly stringent. (See their [Help Center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).)